# NodeJS/Express Build URL using multiple req.query.params

Tags: node.js, express

I have a small express API app which makes calls to an external API. I am trying to build the URL for the external API based on query parameters incoming to my API. I have tried to use an if/else block but the const is only available within that block.

Here is what I have so far:

```
const baseUrl = https://externalapi.com/api&apikey=<APIKEY>;
const response = await axios.get(url);
```

So I want to be able to add query parameters onto the `baseUrl` based on what ones come in, so if a user has a param of `param1` then add this to `baseUrl` to make `url` but if they specify `param2` then add this as well or a combination of one or the other or both

Answer (score 1):

If you set variables within if or else clauses, they need to be variables, not `const`s. And, they need to be declared outside the if / else clauses.

```
let foo
if (a) foo = 'a'
else foo = 'b'
```

A possibility for your application might use [node's URL classes](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html).

```
const targetUrl = new URL('https://externalapi.com/api')
targetUrl.searchParams.append('apikey', '<<SECRET API KEY>>') //SECURITY PROBLEM!

if (a) targetUrl.searchParams.append('objecttype', 'a')
else targetUrl.searchParams.append('objecttype', 'b')
```

You can use the [`.searchParams` property of the `URL` class](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_class_urlsearchparams) to assemble your query.

**Security tip**:  You probably should use POST rather than GET to call this API, and put your sensitive parameters (like your secret API key) into the POST parameters. Parameters on URLs are stored in web server logs. They may be stored in proxy server logs that aren't controlled by you or the provider of your external api.  Explaining how to refactor your code to do that is beyond the scope of this SO answer.